# cargo check fails to build actix-cors

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm following the guides at https://docs.near.org/docs/tutorials/near-indexer

to test out an indexer. However, when I run

```
cargo check
```

An error shows up when building actix-cors:

```
Checking actix-cors v0.6.0-beta.2 (https://github.com/near/actix-extras.git?branch=actix-web-4-beta.6#eb38fbcc)
error[E0053]: method `error_response` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> /<MY HOME DIR>/.cargo/git/checkouts/actix-extras-c37ac6c43c868d63/eb38fbc/actix-cors/src/error.rs:53:5
...
```

Looking at some actix issue here: https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/2185

I think it's due to something wrong in actix beta versioning. Is there a more stable version to use?

My Cargo toml file looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "example-indexer"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
near-indexer = { git = "https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore", rev="a668e4399655af513b0d90e0be694dad2448e6cd" }
actix = "=0.11.0"
openssl-probe = { version = "0.1.2" }
tokio = { version = "1.1", features = ["sync"] }
serde = { version = "1", features = [ "derive" ] }
serde_json = "1.0.55"
```

Comment: Hi! An author of that guide is here. Have you tried the proposed solution in the "Heads up" section? It suggest to take Cargo.lock from nearcore and put it in your projects instead of yours Cargo.lock and rerun `cargo check`. Let me know if that helped, please.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend to use fixed revision for `near-indexer` dependency as in that guide. `nearcore` which contains `near-indexer` constantly developing and we're not always able to update all the guides.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I did as heads-up described as the following:  1. clear my Cargo.lock and copy the content from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/near/nearcore/master/Cargo.lock.  2. rerun cargo check.    It still didn't work for me. Though I'm not sure if I did the correct thing: the heads up section says "replace it with the contents of your project's Cargo.lock file.", but it sounds a little awkward to replace something in a GitHub repo(Unless it means getting into the dependency source code and change it locally?), so I did the opposite: replacing my file with the content from github

Comment: Could you please update your question with content of your Cargo.toml? Thanks

Comment: @khorolets Sure, just appended the toml content

Comment: actix = "=0.11.0-beta.2" should help

Comment: Well actually I updated the version to try to work it around but it still failed. Reverting the version back to "=0.11.0-beta.2"(just as the guide suggests) still result in similar build failure.

Comment: have you tried to build the final repo https://github.com/near-examples/indexer-tutorials/tree/master/example-indexer it is working for me

Comment: Just tried. Also worked for me, thanks!